# Checking a directory for a file in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hey 2 questions within this post, they are probably simple for you experienced js guys :-)

First; why is "filename" undefined inside the `readEntries` when I pass it along?

Second; Why is it always true, when the directory is empty?

Heres my code: I'm calling `getPicturepath` with a string like "women.png".

```
function getPicturePath(filename){
    alert(filename); //is correct
    var reader = DATADIR.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(function(entries, filename){
    alert(filename);//is undefined ???
        var doWeHaveIt = function(entries,filename){
            checkForFile(entries,filename)
            };
        if(doWeHaveIt){
            alert('allready have: '+DATADIR.fullPath+filename);

        } else {
            alert('need to download file: '+filename);
        }
    },onError);
}

function checkForFile(entries,filename){
    console.log("The dir has "+entries.length+" entries.");
    if(entries.indexOf(filename)!=-1){
        alert(filename+' allready exists');
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(filename+" doesn't exists");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reader.readEntries(function(entries, filename){
```

This is the function defining the *parameters* `entries` and `filename`.

For example, this function might do something like:

```
readEntries: function( callback ) {
    // do something, then
    callback( some, datas );
}
```

If you just want to use `filename` in this function, just use it. Like this:

```
function getPicturePath(filename){
    alert(filename); //is correct
    var reader = DATADIR.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(function(entries){
        alert(filename);// is still correct
```

The second part (always true) is because of this:

```
function hi() {}

if ( hi ) {
    // You're always getting there.
}
```

What I wrote is *exactly* what you did. I let you guess how to correct that :-)

Comment: Okay I see, I'm a horrible @ JS. Can you tell me how I can get true/false back from the function checkIfFile....?

Comment: No. I don't want to code for you. I'd rather have you learn something about JS. Like function declaration or function instantiation. Besides, this is really basics. Reading the tutorial I showed you in the chat room would show you how to learn this in less than an hour.